# Minecraft 1.9 freezes if I click on things too quickly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So Minecraft 1.8 was working without a hitch and then when I tried out 1.9 I have tons of trouble.  I can load my world and move around, but if I say open a chest, close it and repeat this 3 times the game will freeze and won't even generate an error message - suffice it to say this is very frustrating.  Things I have tried:

- Running 1.9,1.9.1 and 1.9.2 - all have same crash/freeze
- 1.8 works perfectly
- updating video card drivers
- Updating java
- Reistalling Minecraft
- updating to windows 10 (I was running 8 before)
- restarting my computer
- allocating an extra 3GB of RAM to Minecraft (total of 4GB)

Overall system specs:

Decent computer with 8GB of ram, i7 processor and using admin privileges.

Minecraft: I am using Vanilla Minecraft

I'm really at a loss here so if you have any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: From my personal experience it's hard to say what the issue is without any error messages. I'd say try running version 1.8 again and see if the same issues occur. Then you might be able to narrow down what the issue may be by going through channel logs etc. (So long as when running 1.8 you don't get the same issues)

Comment: Tried that already, 1.8 works beautifully.  The lack of an error message is particularly frustrating

Comment: Error messages as in no crash logs? Maybe the Game Output log will show something?

Comment: I found something when I am trying to search for it... Then I realize its the same person xD                 
http://www.discuzfeed.com/game/eoehzh-minecraft-1-9-freezes-if-i-click-on-things-too-quickly.html

Comment: How much RAM have you dedicated to minecraft? Check this in f3

Answer (score 1):

**I found out, this is a duplicate of**: [What is the "Use VBOs" setting?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177257/what-is-the-use-vbos-setting/177260)

I did everything now for you, and I hope you have all your questions solved.

Try to turn VBOs and VSync on in the Minecraft video options/settings.

**VBO** stands for **"Vertex Buffer Objects"**

It increase your FPS by 5% to 10% on average.
This got added in a snapshot update.

Because the issue you have is, it stops drawing your world, by enabling this it saves the vertex data into your GPU memory at the start.

**VSync** stands for **"Vertical Synchronizationbasically"**

basically synchronizes your frames per second with your monitor refresh rate.

You should have experience for screen tearing!

So it should add maximal FPS which would be 60 FPS cause your monitor can only refresh that much. But if you use your FULL POWER AND WANT ALL FPS then you need to have a good computer otherwise it slowers up stuff.

*If this didn't worked try it with OptiFine, maybe this is a bug so you may contact the minecraft support team but first try to turn those things on, this solved the issue for alot of peoples.*

Comment: Why will this help?  What does it do?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoFCAUtJinc

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDq3tIdpCew

Comment: I am editing the answer so you can read why and what does it do.

Comment: Excellent.  That would be a very good start.

Comment: Done, and because of all those process it causes a crash because Minecraft doesn't work like this for some reasons.

Comment: And doing more of more edits. Minecraft would never add settings that hurts your computer.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue.  I've already tried changing these settings.

Answer (score -2):

This is some kind of Bug! You should probably re-launch minecraft and try to use the latest version. Mojang fixed many bugs in version 1.11.

Hope this helped you!